# Thumbnails view for Google Drive hosted images folder that can be embedded on my site?

Tags: google-drive-api

So I've got a Google Drive folder with a bunch of images that I'd like to embed on my (non-Google) website.

I've got them shared as visible to public, and I can get a list of the images here:

https://googledrive.com/host/0B3jFSjcavNweSWdFMUFfUGJNUEE/

I can embed this view on my site no problem using an iframe.

What'd I'd really like is an embeddable view that shows a thumbnail for each image, rather than a list of filenames and dates ... and put that on an iframe on my site.

Possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google drive hosting changes in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302170/google-drive-hosting-changes-in-url)

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already sorted this yourself by now but I came across your question whilst looking for a way to embed the 'root' directories for a Drive. This should do what you need; you just need to use the #grid option to get the thumbs:

```
<iframe id="298782643" title="SQ 712 Web site photos" 
src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?
authuser=0&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;id=0B3jFSjcavNweSWdFMUFfUGJNUEE#grid" height="800"
width="100%" allowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```